# How to add custom capabilities for Admin Roles in OIM 11G R2 PS3

Tags: entitlements, identity-management, oim

We have a scenario where we have to assign partial Admin Roles for few users in OIM 11G R2 PS3. The OOTB capabilities that are available in OIM does not meet the requirements. I would like to know if there is any way to add custom capabilities somewhere so that it would be available for me to select the same while creating custom Admin Role before assigning it to the user.

Thanks,
Srini

Answer (score 1):

Here is the documentation for creating new Admin roles https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E52734_01/oim/OMUSG/adminrole_mangmnt.htm#BABBIBJA

My only concern would be with whats available permission-wise it still seems to allow viewability to users details across the board.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The guide tells us how to create custom admin role. What I am looking for is how to add custom capabilities to our custom roles. All I can do at present is add only OOTB capabilities from the list to the custom Admin Role I create. I need to some help on how to create custom Capabilities/Permissions similar to ones that are provided OOTB like "Create User", "Modify User" etc.. To be specific, I need a negative capability to be created like "Do not allow users to view/search users in their own Organization"